# Greedy matching in regex(java)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to tokenize the input below using java regex. I believe my expression should greedily match the outer "exec" tokens in the program below.

```
@Test
    public void test(){
        String s = "exec(\n" +
                "    \"command #1\"\n" +
                "    ,\"* * * * *\" //cron string\n" +
                "    ,\"false\" eq exec(\"command #3\")) //condition\n" +
                ")\n" +
                "\n" +  //split here
                "exec(\n" +
                "    \"command #2\" \n" +
                "    ,\"exec(\"command #4\") //condition\n" +
                ");";
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("exec\\s*\\(.*\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matches.add(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(matches);
    }
```

I'm expecting output as

```
[exec(
    "command #1"
    ,"* * * * *" //cron string
    ,"false" eq exec("command #3")) //condition
),exec(
    "command #2" 
    ,"exec("command #4") //condition
);]
```

but get

```
[exec("command #3")), exec("command #4")]
```

Could anyone please help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, The dot character `.` does not match on newline characters. Here, in this case, the "exec" pattern will only match if it occurs on the same line.

You can use [Pattern.DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) to allow matching to be done on newline characters:

```
Pattern.compile("exec\\s*\\(.*\\)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

---

Alternatively `(?s)` can be specified, which is equivalent:

```
Pattern.compile("(?s)exec\\s*\\(.*\\)");
```

Comment: `By default, Java regex Pattern does not match on newline characters` You probably mean that `.` does not match new line by default.